# Scaffold-DbContext create model based on existing database, Package Console throws an exception

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, dbcontext, scaffold

I created a database with `Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio`, added the connection to my visual studio project. 
Then I wanted to use `Scaffold-DbContext` to create a model based on the existing database.
So I input

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=myserver; Database=database; Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

In the `Package-Manager` Console, but I get the error

> The Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNINativeMethodWrapper type initiator triggered an

I can't find anything about this problem and I am wondering if anyone has a solution.

Comment: what version of .Net Core are you using?

Comment: .Net Core 2.1.509

Comment: Check this thread, see if it would set off any alarms: https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/211

Comment: No already checked there.. and the whole internet.